# Certificate based login

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, smartcard, credential-providers

I am currently working on a smartcard based login for windows. For this I develop a credential provider that can communicate with an nfc-enabled smartphone that is used as a replacement for a card reader. Communication between smartphone and cp is done via bluetooth and / or a standard network connection. My current state is that everything works until I want to send down the gathered credentials to LogonUI to start a logon try.

Basically my problem is that I have no idea how to use the certificate I got from the smartcard to log into windows now. The main problem is that I can't seem to find the corresponding apis to reach down the certificate. Does anybody know how this can be done? A link to a proper documentation would help me already. As far as I understand, LogonUI uses kerberos. Are they using the MIT implementation?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO passed into
[ICredentialProvider::SetUsageScenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776026(v=vs.85).aspx)
must return the serialized form of one of the following structs
[KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
[KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Searching the web for each of the structures should turn up code for serializing them.